# Recommended way to make a client

Tags: go

Let's assume that I want to make a client, for example, MySQL client (but my question is generic and not just for MySQL client, any client), this is a sample code

```golang
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:<yourMySQLdatabasepassword>@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()
}
```

I want to move it into a function so I don't have to initialize it all over the place and here my question begins I can do it in various ways and I want to know which one is the recommended way

##### Here is functional way

```golang
func client() (client *sql.DB, err error) {
    client, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:<yourMySQLdatabasepassword>@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return
}
```

##### Global variable way

```golang
var client, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:<yourMySQLdatabasepassword>@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")
```

##### `init` func way

```golang
var Client *sql.DB

func init() {
    Client, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:root@tcp(localhost:3306)/otp")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}
```

##### and finally struct way

```golang
type MSQL struct {
    // Fields...
}

func (m *MSQL) Client() *sql.DB {
    client, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:<yourMySQLdatabasepassword>@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    return client
}

// NewMysql().where(...)
```

I'm really confused here to select which one to follow

Comment: You cannot handle errors with package-level initialization, so that's out the window. // There is no significant difference between initializing in main() or init() or a function called by either of them. // Creating your own type doesn't solve the problem. Whether you have to deal with *sql.DB or *MyType makes no difference.

Answer (score -1):

Exposing a public variable `var Client *sql.DB` is error prone as I can do `<package>.Client = null` from anywhere.

`struct` way is the way to go, As you can work with multiple connection each to a specific database at any time.
You can also use `New()` to pass in a `config` object or other props to customise other `db` props. like `Max Connection`.

```
package database;

type Db struct{
 *db sql.DB
}

func New(driver, connection string) *Db {
 db, err := sql.Open(driver, connection)
 if err != nil {
   panic(err)
 }
 if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
   panic(err)
 }
 /* configure details
 db.SetConnMaxLifetime(conLifeTime)
 db.SetMaxOpenConns(maxOpenConns)
 db.SetMaxIdleConns(maxIdleConns)
 */
 return &Db{db}
}

func (d *Db) Close() error {
 return d.db.Close();
}
```

Its generic, you can pass any `driver` & `connection string` for creating a connection to any `database`.

connection `database.New("mysql", "root:<yourMySQLdatabasepassword>@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/test")`

usage `database.Db.Where(...)`

close connection `database.Db.Close()`